# Kotlin okhttp dynamic header

Tags: android, kotlin, dynamic, http-headers, okhttp

i am using okhttp (not retrofit) to make all my request to the api. It's working perfectly but i am having some trouble to make dynamique header. here is what i did :

```
private fun buildRequest(url: String, methode: Method = Method.GET, filters: Map<String, String> = mapOf(): Request? {

var builder = FormBody.Builder()
builder.add("body", "test")
val request = Request.Builder()
                .url(url)
                .addHeader("API-Key", apikey)
                .post(formBody)
                .build()
}
```

Problem is that i got a map filter that represent some header i need to add, but those are not hard coded but they are dynamique, it can be for exemple :

```
var filters = mapOf("limit" to "10", "sort" to "date")
```

But i can't do a static addHeader for the filters because i don't know if i am going to have some or not or which are they going to be.

My idea was to use newBuilder like this :

```
if (!filters.isNullOrEmpty()){
    filters.forEach{
       request.newBuilder()
       request.addHeader(it.key, it.value)
              .build()
```

}

Problem is that this doesn't add my new header to the call. I am I missing something on how to use newBuilder ? or is there a way to manage dynamique header with okhttp ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `toHeaders()` extension function of `map` to convert your `map` object to `Headers`.

All key-value pairs of the map can be easily added to headers like this

```
val request = Request.Builder()
                .url(url)
                .headers(filters.toHeaders())
```

> Note - Using `headers()` would replace all previously added headers of
> the request builder.

You can also add headers to `request` builder later, on using `newBuilder()`

```
request.newBuilder()
     .headers(filters.toHeaders())
```

Comment: Worked like a charm thanks very much. Also be careful because it's remove all the precedent header that you added with .addHeader so if you want to use both you need to use .headers first then add with .addHeader everything you want after.